# How to Sync Prod SC with QA SC in businees Hours without making the PROD site Read-Only

Tags: 2013

I am in need to do some testing in 2013 QA Site Collection but the 2013 QA Site Collection is not in SYNC with the 2013 PROD Site Collection. Is there any easy way to do that without making the PROD site ready only during office hours.

The PROD site has custom workflows and InfoPath forms so what is the best approach and please mention the steps.

1. Backup-SPSite -Identity "site collection url" -Path "backup file path"
   Restore-SPSite -Identity "site collection url" -Path "backup file path"
2. Export-SPWeb [-Identity] "site url or GUID" -Path "backup file path"
   Import-SPWeb [-Identity] "site url or GUID" -Path "backup file path"
3. DB Detach/Attach
   Would this method change the PROD url to QA automatically as the urls are different once the detach attach is done.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

1. **Backup-SpSite** By default, the site collection will be set to read-only for the duration of the backup to reduce the potential for
   user activity during the backup operation to corrupt the backup. If
   you have SQL Server Enterprise Edition, we recommend that
   UseSqlSnapshot parameter be used because this ensures a valid backup
   while it allows users to continue reading and writing to the site
   collection during the backup.

So if you have enterprise edition then this is option is good.

1. I dont think import/export is good option.
2. You can use the DB backup and restore method. it is recommended approach but read-only about the backup, i am not sure.

Comment: I Tried the Backup-SPSite and got the below error  on the top of the screen "We Apologize  for any convenience but we have made the site read only while we were making some improvements" .This error wont go off even after the BackUp was completed.I ran Powershell to the make siteLock None but still no change and the site is still ReadOnly.

Comment: That's weird... What is ur command? Did u check site collection lock status from central admin

Comment: I used  Backup-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak and the CA shows the status Locked. I used the below Powershell to Unlock it but no change  stsadm -o setsitelock -url "url" - lock none

Comment: have you tried to unlock from central admin?